# Why decltype(auto) infers T& as return type, while dedicated T& does not?

Tags: c++, templates, type-inference, decltype, decltype-auto

Consider this snippet:

```
#include <stdexcept>

template <typename T> class MyClass;

template <typename T> struct MyClass<T &> {

  constexpr T &foo() && {
    return value != nullptr ? std::move(*value)
                            : throw std::runtime_error("foo");
  }

  constexpr decltype(auto) bar() && {
    return value != nullptr ? std::move(*value)
                            : throw std::runtime_error("bar");
  }

  T *value;
};

int main() {
  const int &good = MyClass<int &>{}.bar();
  const int &bad = MyClass<int &>{}.foo();
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/E6M6v7Kb3)

Why is return specification `decltype(auto)` in method `bar` working, while `T&` in `foo` does not?

Comment: Who said it's deducing `T&`? If it was, don't you think a non-const reference in `main` would work?

Comment: better describe the symptoms rather than only your interpretation. The error message should be included in the question

Comment: @molbdnilo - No, it deduces `T&&`.

Comment: Sidenote: This is a case where I would just use a standard guard clause instead of trying to muck up readability with ternary statements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why decltype(auto) infers T& as return type

No, the return type of `bar()` is `T&&`, i.e. `int&&` in this case. For [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype):

> if the value category of expression is xvalue, then decltype yields T&&;

`std::move(*value)` is an xvalue-expression, so the deduced return type is `T&&`.

On the other hand, the return type of `foo` is specified as `T&`, but `std::move(*value)` is an xvalue (rvalue) and can't be bound to `T&`, i.e. an lvalue-reference to non-const.

Comment: Is there a way to return the value as a reference?

Comment: @Juergen You can specify return type as `T&&` (which is same as the return type of `bar`).